# How to pull data from a DB to compare with rest api response from karate

Tags: karate

I see some documentation in github - https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/8ba369f690bcdda0d779c41128b96a1d6684ddcc/karate-demo/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/demo/util/DbUtils.java

But wanted to know more like - does it support DB testing of any database with JDBC driver support, Cassandra, MongoDB.
It would be great if I get to see more documentation/feature tests for db validation using karate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just a demo example for JDBC, you are expected to write a similar utility in your project using this example.

Refer to how to do [Java Interop](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java) in the doc. And the `dogs.feature` in the demo examples.